# Why can making a compressed archive (tar + pigz) result in a file that is substantially larger than the sum of the original files?

Tags: bash, pipe, compression, tar

I have about 700 folders containing relatively heavy files (10-40gb each), and I'm trying to make a compressed archive out of them.

When I use `tar cf - ~/folder/* | pigz -p 30 > ~/folder/archive.tar.gz`, I run out of my storage space (~13tb), which is larger than the size of my original files.

If I just `tar` the original files without compressing them, the resulting archive is about the same size as the sum of the original files (~8tb).

I tried compressing a small subset of my folders, and while `pigz` did not reduce the size by much, at least it did not increase the size...

What can be the issue here?

ps Not sure if it's relevant, but some of the heavy files in my folders are in a compressed format

Comment: my first guess would be problems with compressing already-compressed files; what happens if you `tar/pigz` **only** the uncompressed files? do you see the explosion in final file size??  if the answer is 'no' then this would seem to imply (to me) that there is an issue with compressing already-compressed files

Comment: @mark: Ok. I probably should have looked at pigz's source before writing that comment.

Comment: pigz or gzip will expand large incompressible data by at most 0.03%.

Comment: Have you try with old `zip`, it do all this?

Comment: @markp-fuso, so I tried compressing only uncompressed files at first, and that worked fine. But then, I tried compressing only about half of the folders (containing both compressed and uncompressed files), and it also didn't cause any issues with storage. This is perplexing...